# Wiremock : Forward the application request to external server using the wiremock proxying

Tags: selenium, mocking, wiremock

I am using Wiremock API with selenium as a proxy server to alter certain browser ajax calls. I started the Wiremock with certain mappings and put the proxy in the browser through selenium. Now I can access the only mapped URLs for the rest of the request getting 404. It seems wire mock is not forwarding the unmapped calls to the internet.

Is there any way to do this? or wire mock can't be used with selenium to mock only a few ajax calls.

Comment: Have you checked out the documentation on forward proxy? http://wiremock.org/docs/proxying/#running-as-a-browser-proxy

Comment: yes I tried all of them.  even in the standalone mode i can access only mapped urls.